# Dictionary and For loop issues in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, for-loop, dictionary

how do I go about getting each value in a dictionary array if this is my dictionary .

```
        rebDictionary= New Dictionary(Of String, String())

    rebDictionary.Add("wrd", {"yap", "tap"})
```

i tried `For Each rtbval As String In rebDictionary.value`

but that does not work at all

Comment: Do you mean that you want all of the `string`s in all of the `array`s in your dictionary's list of `Value`s?  Also: in what way does it not work?  Do you get an error, or is the result not what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values collection property is named [`Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx), so try this:

```
For Each rtbval As String() In rebDictionary.Values
```

However, you're gonna iterate over a collection of `String()`, because your dictionary is `Of(String, String())`.

You can iterate over keys (which are `String`): `rebDictionary.Keys` or use LINQ `SelectMany` to iterate over flatten list of strings taken from you dictionary `Values`:

```
For Each rtbval as String In rebDictionary.Values.SelectMany(Function(x) x)
```

Comment: Except that the `Values` are not `String`, they are `String()` - I don't think it's clear what the expected result is.

Comment: @DanPuzey You're absolutely right! Already updated my answer to provide some additional possible ways here.

Comment: Fixed your second sample to actually use `SelectMany` as you suggested :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following code iterates through all keys and values. You can select whichever parts you want/don't want:

```
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String()) In rebDictionary
        Debug.WriteLine("Key:" + kvp.Key)
        For Each stringValue As String In kvp.Value
            Debug.WriteLine(" Value:" + stringValue)
        Next
    Next
```

You *can* just iterate through the keys:

```
    For Each key As String In rebDictionary.Keys
        Debug.WriteLine("Key:" + key)
    Next
```

*Or* through the values:

```
    For Each value As String() In rebDictionary.Values
        For Each stringValue As String In value
            Debug.WriteLine("value:" + stringValue)
        Next
    Next
```

But doing either of those probably isn't as useful as you don't know the corresponding key or value and I doubt that iterating through the key value pairs is likely to be much slower.